# Is there a way to set some data into an image

Tags: php, image-processing

Let me explain what I am trying to do,  I am building a command line tool with PHP that uses these programs to optimize images for the web...

`imagemagick` to determine file type and convert non-animated gif's to png
`gifsicle` to optimize Animated Gif images
`jpegtran` to optimize jpg images
`pngcrush` to optimize png image
`pngquant` to optimize png images to png8 format
`pngout` to optimize png images to png8 format

This is a pretty heavy process to be running, luckily it is done very infrequently but I would still like to optimize as much as I can.

Right now to process around 12 images takes roughly 76 seconds.  So you can see it is a slow process, imagine 100 images.

I would really like to somehow, mark an image as optimized somehow, so when I am loading a batch of images, the first thing it does is run through ImageMagick to get the exact file type, would be nice if I could somehow embed a message that says this image is already optimized as much as it can be, and then when I am reading images in, if it detects a message it will know to not waste valuable time running that particular image through all the other programs, if this is possible, it could greatly increase speed.

Please help me, I am not used to working with images like this, is this possible even, if it is what is it called and how could I achieve it?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Why not move the files to another directory once they've been processed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to include a flag in the image itself then that would be served to the clients. It would add to the filesize of your images thus negating some of your optimisation.

### Suggestions

#### Keep a reference of the status

Keep a catalog in a file in the same directory - much like the [Windows `Thumbs.db`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_thumbnail_cache#Thumbs.db) file.

Another option would be to keep the record in a database or datastore such as [Redis](http://redis.io) or [Memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php).

#### Move after processing

You could move the files to a different directory once they are processed (as @Jordan mentions).

#### Change the filename to indicate it is processed

Another option would be to append an extra "extension" onto the file name for example:

```
my_image.processed.jpg
```

### Embedding data in images

#### Steganography

Usually this is used for attempting to hide covert data in an image and it is called [Steganography](http://www.garykessler.net/library/steganography.html). It is not really suited to this use case however.

#### EXIF data

You could write it into the EXIF data of an image, but this would be **JPEG and TIFF only** as far as I am aware. There is a [PHP library available called PEL](http://lsolesen.github.com/pel/) for writing and reading EXIF data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Comment` field to tag your image as already optimised, like this:

```
convert x.jpg -set comment "Optimised" x.jpg
```

Then, when you are processing, you can extract it like this:

```
identify -format "%c" x.jpg
Optimised
```